# Relationship between AudioKit MusicTrackManager addPitchBend value and SoundpipeAudioKit PitchShifter?

Tags: audiokit

I'm using the AppleSequencer to add notes to a track with a given noteNumber, velocity, position and duration.

I would also like some notes to be pitch bent by a certain amount (number of semitones), for a certain duration.

I tried track.addPitchBend to add a pitchBend events to the midicallback - I add multiple of these in increment of the position to try to get a smooth pitch bending effect.

In the midi callback, I get the expected pitchwheel midi event with status 224 and data1 and data2 having the lsb and msb of the pitchBend value

I'm trying to use PitchShifter to accomplish the necessary pitch bending.

The PitchShifter uses the shift value in semitones.

The MusicTrackManger's addPitchBend uses a value between 0 to 16383, with the default being 8192 (for no pitch bending).

Is there an existing convention for the value and how it translates to semitones?

Thanks,
Sridhar

PS - Is my approach of adding multiple addPitchBend midi events to try to smooth out an automated pitch bending effect the right way to go about it?

Comment: I think this may answer my question - http://midi.teragonaudio.com/tech/midispec/wheel.htm

Comment: "A combined value of 0x2000 is meant to indicate that the Pitch Wheel is centered (ie, the sounding notes aren't being transposed up or down). Higher values transpose pitch up, and lower values transpose pitch down."

Comment: "The Pitch Wheel range is usually adjustable by the musician on each MIDI device. For example, although 0x2000 is always center position, on one MIDI device, a 0x3000 could transpose the pitch up a whole step, whereas on another device that may result in only a half step up. The GM spec recommends that MIDI devices default to using the entire range of possible Pitch Wheel message values (ie, 0x0000 to 0x3FFF) as +/- 2 half steps transposition (ie, 4 half-steps total range). The Pitch Wheel Range (or Sensitivity) is adjusted via an RPN controller message."